# What is the Music Playing Behind Monty Python's Spanish Inquisition Closing Credits?

Tags: soundtrack, monty-python

At 1:28 in the included video, our Spanish Inquisition heroes rush to catch the bus to the studio.  Hurried chase music plays in the background as the credits roll.

What is the name/composer of that music?

Answer (score 7):

"The Devil's Gallop" by Charles Williams